# How many queueable calls can we do from trigger

Tags: apex, callout

Can I enqueue queueable for all 200 records of trigger context? By 200 I mean 1 for each record? I want to do an integration call for every record updated and since the endpoint system only accepts 1 record at a time - there’s no way I can send all the data together.

Comment: If you are talking about per transaction we have a limit of 50 queueable jobs

Comment: I imagine that the downvotes on this one are because of the lack of research. This information, being a governor limit, is well documented. It's also presented to you in debug logs with the default log levels (specifically, the "system" log level needs to be "debug" or higher).

Answer (score 4):

That depends on whether you are already in a queueable transaction or not. If you are, the maximum is 1, otherwise, it is 50. Please note **[Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)**:

> - Maximum number of Apex jobs added to the queue with `System.enqueueJob`
>
>   - Synchronous Limit: 50
>   - Asynchronous Limit: 1

Answer (score 2):

As per @Adrian Larson's answer, you are very limited on the number of queueables you can enqueue from within a trigger (or any part of a given transaction against the Salesforce org).

Indeed, I would strongly advise against enqueuing any queueables directly from an apex SObject trigger because you cannot control the number of records that a given DML operation does and therefore the number of times your trigger is invoked.

If you have a DML updating more than 200 records while already in an asynchronous context and you try to raise a queueable even just once per call to the trigger (remember that a trigger is called with chunks of up to 200 records at a time, so is called multiple times when more than 200 records are operated on in a given DML), you will have a governor limit error since (as Adrian pointed out) you can only enqueue 1 queueable while in that asynchronous context.

Personally I would flag the record is needing to be sent and have some unrelated process, such as a scheduled job that runs every few minutes (there are better ways to do this, but it's a very long explanation), find the flagged records, send them one at a time to the external system and clear the flag.

Be aware that you can perform up to 100 callouts per transaction, so your process for sending these records to the external system can still send 100 records from a single invocation, using separate callouts per record. Again, this is covered in the [governor limits documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm).